# Find  and  such that the system has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image]

I want find all (a,b) for system have infinitely solutions. I was try
[image]

What should i do next? Can I conclude $(a,b)=(-3,9)$ is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elimination is correct.
Now, we argue looking at the last row.

1. If $a\neq -3$, the system has a unique solution.
2. If $a=-3$ but $b\neq 9$, the system is inconsistent. There is no solution.
3. If $a=-3$ but $b=9$ then there are infinetly many solution.

So the answer of $A3.$ is $(a,b)=(-3,9)$. I think the answer of $A2.$ is $(x,y,z)=(1,2,-1).$

Comment: Thank sir. I was wondering if (-3,9) is the complete answer or not. But now  it's clear.